# Convert an Task<Bitmap> to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, xamarin, return-type

In Xamarin, how can I convert a return type of '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Android.Graphics.Bitmap>`' to '`Android.Graphics.Bitmap`'

Here is my method:

```
private async Task<Bitmap> GetBitmapFromUriAsync(string uri)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    using (var data = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri))
    {
        if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
        {
            return await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(data);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I am needing to set the result of the above method to an `ImageView`

This is the code that I currently have:

```
gridViewItem.image = GetBitmapFromUriAsync("http://image.png");
```

Here is the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Android.Graphics.Bitmap>' to 'Android.Graphics.Bitmap'
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have added the await keyword as follows: 
`gridViewItem.image = await GetBitmapFromUriAsync("http://image.png");`

This is the error that I am getting:

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'
```

How do I modify the return type to be `Task`, yet still return a `Bitmap`?

Comment: The error you are getting is descriptive enough. You have to make the method in which `GetBitmapFromUriAsync("http://image.png");` is called async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
gridViewItem.image = GetBitmapFromUriAsync("http://image.png").Result;
```

will give you the bitmap, but will do it **synchronously**. If you want to take advantage of the asynchronous calls in .NET 4.5, you should call

```
gridViewItem.image = await GetBitmapFromUriAsync("http://image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
gridViewItem.image = GetBitmapFromUriAsync("http://image.png").Result;
```